# API googletrans traduzindo erroneamente textos

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-translate

Estou tentando criar uma aplicação em Python onde preciso traduzir alguns textos, e para executar tal tarefa, estou utilizando a API `googletrans`.

```
text = 'Back in the day people used to go to many different places to buy the things they needed at home. They used to go to the butcher for meat and chicken, to the fruit market for fresh fruit, and to the bakery for bread. Nowadays, most people just go to one place to get everything they need. They can buy fruit, vegetables, bread, meat, milk and frozen foods at their local supermarket.'

translator = Translator()
result = translator.translate(text, "pt", "en").text

print("Original:", text)
print("-----------------")
print("Tradução:", result)
```

O problema é que quase todas as traduções dos textos que eu coloco possuem problemas (problemas que não acontecem quando se traduz o mesmo texto no Google Tradutor pelo browser).

Veja abaixo o *output* do código acima:

> Original: Back in the day people used to go to many different places to buy the things they needed at home. They used to go to the butcher for meat and chicken, to the fruit market for fresh fruit, and to the bakery for bread. Nowadays, most people just go to one place to get everything they need. They can buy fruit, vegetables, bread, meat, milk and frozen foods at their local supermarket.

> Tradução: Para trás nos dias as pessoas costumavam ir para muitos lugares diferentes para comprar as coisas de que precisavam em casa. Eles usaram para ir ao açougue de carne e frango, para o mercado de frutas para frutas frescas, e até a padaria para pão. Hoje em dia, a maioria das pessoas simplesmente ir a um lugar para obter tudo o que precisam. Eles podem comprar frutas, legumes, pão, carne, leite e alimentos congelados em seu supermercado local.

Abaixo está a [tradução](https://translate.google.com.br/?hl=pt-BR#view=home&op=translate&sl=en&tl=pt&text=Back%20in%20the%20day%20people%20used%20to%20go%20to%20many%20different%20places%20to%20buy%20the%20things%20they%20needed%20at%20home.%20They%20used%20to%20go%20to%20the%20butcher%20for%20meat%20and%20chicken%2C%20to%20the%20fruit%20market%20for%20fresh%20fruit%2C%20and%20to%20the%20bakery%20for%20bread.%20Nowadays%2C%20most%20people%20just%20go%20to%20one%20place%20to%20get%20everything%20they%20need.%20They%20can%20buy%20fruit%2C%20vegetables%2C%20bread%2C%20meat%2C%20milk%20and%20frozen%20foods%20at%20their%20local%20supermarket.) feita pelo Google Tradutor através do browser:

> No passado, as pessoas costumavam ir a muitos lugares diferentes para
> comprar o que precisavam em casa. Eles costumavam ir ao açougue para
> carne e frango, ao mercado de frutas para frutas frescas e à padaria
> para pão. Hoje em dia, a maioria das pessoas vai a um lugar para obter
> tudo o que precisa. Eles podem comprar frutas, legumes, pão, carne,
> leite e alimentos congelados no supermercado local.

Estou fazendo algo de errado? Como posso fazer o `googletrans` traduzir exatamente como o Google Tradutor do browser?

Detalhes do ambiente:

- Python 3.7.6
- googletrans: [3.0.0](https://pypi.org/project/googletrans/3.0.0/)
- Windows 7 (x64)

Comment: Realmente parece ser um problema com a biblioteca, pode ver [aqui](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/138)  e [aqui](https://github.com/ssut/py-googletrans/issues/157)

Comment: Se for o caso, pode usar [a lib da Google Cloud](https://cloud.google.com/translate/docs/basic/translating-text#translate_translate_text-python)

Comment: Precisa pagar ou criar alguma conta para usar esse Google Cloud ?

Comment: Não é necessário pagar, você precisa apenas de uma conta Google. Você pode seguir esse [Guia básico](https://googleapis.dev/python/translation/latest/index.html)

Comment: Qual versão do Python3? Qual versão do do googletrans? Qual sistema operacional?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento respondi na edição da pergunta.

Comment: @JeanExtreme002 claro que são necessárias, para configurar o ambiente exatamente ou próximo ao seu para então poder determinar se é falha NA VERSÃO  que você esta usando da LIB ou é falha baseado em algo do sistema operacional (o que indica bug na lib também) ou se é falha/conflito na versão do python (o que indica bug na lib também) ... Isso tudo sempre é necessário, se fosse um código seu, aberto, realmente não precisa, mas o problema é em uma lib de terceiros.

Comment: Editei a pergunta, porque o espaço não é para questionar como acha que uma pergunta de ser ou não formulada, o espaço é para explicar o seu problema e informar o ambiente que usa, também não use tags que não tem haver com problema da pergunta, a tag [tag:api] não é para ser usada quando o problema é sobre libs de terceiros. Se discorda da necessidade de adicionar as configs e versões do seu ambiente pode levar o questionamento para o https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/ - Editei a pergunta para melhorar o texto e detalhes e reabri ela.

Answer (score -2):

Seu código está correto mas o problema que você está utilizando uma biblioteca que traduz tudo de maneira literal

Use a biblioteca translate utilizando pip install translate no terminal

Ele faz as traduções usando diretamente o google tradutor.

Eis aqui o código que fiz:

```
from translate import Translator

translator = Translator(to_lang="pt")
translation1 = translator.translate("""Hi Everyone,
New rule (and I can't believe I have to say this) 
please don't give birth in the voice channel.
It makes people very uncomfortable.""")
print(translation1)
```

E esse foi o output:

```
Olá a todos,
Nova regra (e não acredito que tenho que dizer isso), 
por favor, não dê à luz no canal de voz.
Isso deixa as pessoas muito desconfortáveis.
```

E caso ainda duvide, olha a tradução do google tradutor:

```
Olá a todos,
Nova regra (e eu não posso acreditar que eu tenho que dizer isso) 
por favor, não dê à luz no canal de voz.
Isso deixa as pessoas muito desconfortáveis.
```

A diferença é mínima.